# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: extra data after last expected column

Tags: csv, greenplum, dbeaver

I am trying to import a csv file to postgres db:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dwh.stg.products_mapping_temp_ext (
    date varchar,
    product_code varchar,
    product_name varchar,
    product_operation_code varchar,
    product_operation_name varchar,
    department varchar,
    process_code varchar,
    process_name varchar,
    process_stage_code varchar,
    process_stage_name varchar
)
LOCATION (
    'gpfdist://worker:6666/dags/csv/quarter_kpi/products_mapping_temp_ext.csv'
) ON ALL
FORMAT 'CSV' ( delimiter ';' null '' escape '"' quote '"' header fill missing fields )
ENCODING 'WIN1251';
```

The content of my CSV is:

```
date; product_code; product_name; product_operation_code; product_operation_name;department;process_code;process_name ;process_stage_code;process_stage_name.
```

function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION etl.fnc_products_mapping_temp_sa_load()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $$
     BEGIN 
     TRUNCATE TABLE stg.products_mapping_temp; 
     INSERT INTO stg.products_mapping_temp(
        "date",
        product_code,
        product_name,
        product_operation_code,
        product_operation_name,
        department,
        process_code,
        process_name,
        process_stage_code,
        process_stage_name
    ) 
     SELECT 
        to_date("date", 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
        product_code,
        product_name,
        product_operation_code,
        product_operation_name,
        department,
        ltrim(rtrim(process_code)),
        ltrim(rtrim(process_name)),
        ltrim(rtrim(process_stage_code)),
        ltrim(rtrim(process_stage_name)) 
    FROM stg.products_mapping_temp_ext; 
     END; 
$$
EXECUTE ON ANY;
```

Comment: Please show a sample of actual csv data. Are there any lines with extra columns?

Comment: 22.04.2022;11.01.01.01;"Пакет услуг ""БИЗНЕС-ВЗЛЕТ""";400;Проводка по счетам 8 класса в ДРП;Сервисный офис;БК.2.1;Предоставление услуг по открытию, закрытию и ведению банковских счетов;БК.2.1.11.1.;11.1. Взимание комиссионного вознаграждения за открытие/переоформление/закрытие  счета.;